# Is the returned string from a recursive function going out of scope?

Tags: c++, string, recursion, graph

Giving as simple of a background context as I possibly can, which I don't think is necessary for what I'm trying to figure out at the moment, I'm trying to implement a graph representation via adjacency list, in my case being an unordered map that has a string key to a struct value that contains Vertex object pointers (the object that is identified by the key), and a vector of its dependencies. The goal is to output a critical path via a sort of DAG resolution algorithm.

So when I need to output a critical path, I'm trying to use a recursive solution I implemented. Basically it looks for a base case (if a job has no dependencies), return a print out of its id, start time and length. Otherwise, find the longest running (in terms of time length) job in its dependency list and call the function on that until you find a job with no dependencies. There can be more than one critical path, and I don't have to print out all of them.

MY QUESTION: I'm debugging this at the moment, and it has no problem printing out a job's properties when its a base case. If it has to recurse through though, the string always comes back as empty (""). Is the recursive call making my string go out of scope by the time it comes back to the caller? Here is the code structure for it. All of the functions below are public members of the same Graph class.

```
string recurseDeps(unordered_map<string, Dependencies>& umcopy, string key) {
        if (umcopy[key].deps.empty()) {
            string depPath = " ";
            string idarg, starg, larg, deparg;

            idarg = key;
            starg = " " + to_string(umcopy[key].jobatKey->getStart());
            larg = " " + to_string(umcopy[key].jobatKey->getStart() + umcopy[key].jobatKey->getLength());

            umcopy.erase(key);
            return depPath + idarg + starg + larg;
        }
        else {
            string lengthiestDep = umcopy[key].deps[0];

            for (auto i = begin(umcopy[key].deps); i != end(umcopy[key].deps); i++) {
                if (umcopy[*i].jobatKey->getLength() >
                    umcopy[lengthiestDep].jobatKey->getLength()) {
                    lengthiestDep = *i;
                }
            }

            recurseDeps(umcopy, lengthiestDep);
        }
    }

    string criticalPath(unordered_map<string, Dependencies>& um, vector<Vertex*> aj) {
        unordered_map<string, Dependencies> alCopy = um;

        string path = aj[0]->getId();

        for (auto i = begin(aj); i != end(aj); i++) {
            if (um[(*i)->getId()].jobatKey->getLength() >
                um[path].jobatKey->getLength()) {
                path = (*i)->getId();
            }
        }

        return recurseDeps(alCopy, path);
    }
```

Later on down in the class members, a function called readStream() calls the functions like so:

```
cout << time << criticalPath(adjList, activeJobs) << endl;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning the value when you recurse. You're making the recursive call, but discarding the value and just falling off the end of the function. You need to do:

```
return recurseDeps(umcopy, lengthiestDep);
```

Comment: Solved it! Many thanks, completely went over my head how trivial that was.

Comment: 99% of the time when someone posts a problem with a recursive function, this is the reason.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to answer your question, since you return by value the string is *copied* so no need to worry about variables going out of scope.

Secondly, and a much bigger problem, is that not all paths of your recursive function actually returns a value, which will lead to *undefined behavior*. If your compiler doesn't already warn you about this, you should enable more warnings.

Comment: To make this explicit, the recursive call in `recurseDeps()` should be `return recurseDeps(umcopy, lengthiestDep);`